# CentOS Gnome only showing 1TB on 6TB Server?

Tags: linux, centos, raid, software-raid

I just bought a new server and want to use it to store files, It has 2x 3TB hard drives. I Set them up in raid 0 as i don't need any redundancy.

I don't know much about servers and command-lines ive just set it up based on guides off the net. Have i done something wrong?

In gnome i only see a single hard drive which is 1TB:

[image]

This is what i get when i type fdisk -l

```
 [root@CentOS-65-64-minimal leech]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00046863

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1        2089    16777216+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2            2089        2155      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3            2155      135829  1073741824+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb4          135830      364802  1839219160    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5          135830      364802  1839217112+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00024298

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        2089    16777216+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2            2089        2155      524288+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3            2155      135829  1073741824+  83  Linux
/dev/sda4          135830      364802  1839219160    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5          135830      364802  1839217112+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/md127: 1099.5 GB, 1099511431168 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 268435408 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md126: 536 MB, 536805376 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 131056 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md125: 17.2 GB, 17179738112 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 4194272 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md124: 1883.4 GB, 1883358167040 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 459804240 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

`/proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md124 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb5[1]
      1839216960 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md125 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb1[1]
      16777088 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb2[1]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb3[1]
      1073741632 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Please post `/proc/mdstat`. Also, using the MBR partition scheme is not that great with disks that big.

Comment: I get permission denied even as root user trying to run that?

Comment: It's not a command but a text file. You can get its contents with any text editor, `cat`, `more`, `less`,...

Comment: Ok sorry, Here it is: http://pastebin.com/jUWpnVGn

Comment: Does that mean its in raid 1?

Answer (score 0):

It seems some sort of mistake occurred during the partition setup. You currently have one disk without any RAID partitions, which is probably (part of) what you see in the GUI. The other disk is filled with single-device (“create with missing device”) RAID-1 partitions. I'm not overly familiar with the CentOS installation process, so I can't guarantee that setting up RAID-0 there is possible.

Basically, since this appears to be a new installation, you should start over completely. I recommend using RAID-1 for the operating system and RAID-0 for data. You can always create data partitions later, so the most important part is getting the `/` partition to be RAID-1 or -0 or whatever you desire.

If you're open to learn something about Linux operating systems, try Arch Linux, by the way. It comes with great guides for many usual and not-so-usual configurations. Since the installation is performed by hand, you can create virtually any RAID configuration right away.